# Accessing a remoted forwarded port from a third host

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have two servers server1 and server2
from server1 issue the following command

```
ssh user2@server2 -N -R 9080:localhost:80
```

Now from server2 I issue the following command:

```
wget http://localhost:9080
```

this works the file downloaded by wget is the file hosted by the webserver running on server1:80

From a independent machine I issue the following command

```
wget http://server2:9080
```

This doesn't work - the command eventually times out. I don't see any clues in server2's syslogs.

I've replaced all my firewall rules on server2 with:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

From the independent machine, connect to

```
wget http://server1:80
```

...and let server1's SSH tunnel carry it to server2's 9080 port.